# Can we deduce this from partial differential equation?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $W(t,x,y)$ be a function that satisfies the partial differential equation

$$\frac{\partial W}{\partial t}+ a\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial x^2} + b \frac{\partial^2W}{\partial y^2} + c\frac{\partial W}{\partial x} + d\frac{\partial W}{\partial y}+ eW = 0$$

If we are given that the "final condition" $W(T, x, y) = f(x,T)$ does *not* depend on $y$, can I deduce (or under which conditions) that $$\frac{\partial W}{\partial y}  = 0$$?

Comment: Are there any boundary conditions?

Comment: @JohnMa not specified, but feel free to take whatever you want :)

Comment: You could start with any domain so that there are uniquness of solution given the "final" and boundary conditions. If the boundary condition is also independent of $y$, then one can solve $V_t + aV_{xx} + cV_x  =0$ and find out some $V(x, t)$, then this $V$ also satisfy your equation as $V_y = 0$. By uniqueness, this is the only solution.

Comment: @JohnMa Thank you! I should have commented on the uniqueness case.. It's undoubtely important but I was wondering it there is something a little more general :-)